# tailwind.config.js set new colors vars with previously defined colors

Tags: tailwind-css

In `tailwind.config.js` im trying to define `green` at the same time as setting `header`... is this possible? If not; is there another way? Can these be modified at runtime?

```
{
    theme: {
      colors: {
        'green': '#36D585',
        'header': theme => theme('colors.green')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `header` config?
If you want to change the color of specific elements you need to use their respective classes within the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want an alias of `header` to be the same color as `green`, I would suggest defining an object containing your colors, then referencing that in your config exports, since the `theme` function is only available in [top-level theme keys](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#referencing-other-values).

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const customColors = {
  green: '#36D585',
  // ...
}

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      ...customColors,
      header: customColors.green
    }
  }
}
```

As for changing things at runtime, you wouldn't be able to dynamically update the colors in Tailwind since the CSS is generated at build time. However, you can use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to dynamically update things in the browser. See the [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#naming-your-colors) for more information.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      header: 'var(--color-header)'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* main.css or where your CSS is */
:root {
  /* updating this value with Javascript will reactively update the colors */
  --color-header: #36D585;
  /* ... */
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```